# Add auth to specific file with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to add auth to specific file but it doesn`t work.
I use the default Zf2 .htaccess and I added the section with  only.
When I add the section  and open http://example.com/build.php redirect me to index.php. When I remove section  its open build.php.
How I can add auth only ont build.php and open it without redirect me to index.php?
The htaccess is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]

<Files build.php>
AuthName "Permission Required"
AuthUserFile "/home/test/.htpasswd"
Require valid-group
AuthType Basic
</Files>
```

Comment: There is no `valid-group` option for the `Require` directive. You can use `Require valid-user` or `Require group <some-group>` instead.

Comment: After you have authenticated, your file (as everything other) being rewritten to `index.php` by the last `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Yes I already fixed option to valid-user but this is not the mail problem

Comment: Ok but how to fix this RewriteRule. I want all request to be redirected to index.php without build.php

Comment: I didn't note the first rewrite rule, sorry. According to the very first RewriteCond, any file with non-zero size should be served (not rewritten). So, check the size.

Comment: The size is not zero. When I remove the section <Files> I can load build.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79215/discussion-between-umka-and-anton-sh).

Answer (score 1):

My hosting company helped me.
They added the next line and everything its works right now.

ErrorDocument 401 default